# Use custom image for Google+1 button?

Tags: google-plus-one

I want to include a "google+1" button on a page, yet I want to use a custom image with a custom size for it and preferably without javascript, much like is possible to do with Facebook and Twitter. I don't care if it don't show the count number for now.

Comment: Make sure this doesn't violate their TOS. Changing the look of the FB like button is a violation of FB TOS.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Finally! Found a nice solution to this problem. So simple and working :) Hope it helps you!

```
<a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=ADD_YOUR_URL" >
    <img src="path_to_your_image" alt="Google+" title="Google+"/>
</a>
```

Source: http://notesofgenius.com/how-develop-custom-google-plus-button/

Comment: There is an updated url: https://plus.google.com/share?url=[URL]. If you open it up as a popup it automatically resizes to fit the window, unlike the original link.

Comment: I wonder if with this method it is possible to specify a thumbnail image for the shared page, instead of letting Google pick one at its discretion.

Comment: Just a little warning.

To share is different from +1.

"Add this button to content across your site to make sharing on Google+ easy. This button is perfect for content that users may want to share but not +1 (e.g. news or controversial content)."

https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/

Comment: It is impossible to get callback in this case.

Comment: Is it possible to load the content that opens in a modal (lightbox) ? instead in new tab/window ?

Answer (score 13):

This is the official example from the [google developers page](https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/share/#sharelink):

Also consider that the URL was updated.

```
<a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url={URL}" onclick="javascript:window.open(this.href, '', 'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=600,width=600');return false;">
  <img src="https://www.gstatic.com/images/icons/gplus-64.png" alt="Share on Google+"/>
</a>
```

Comment: http://skyzerblogger.blogspot.com/2014/11/embed-facebook-likeshare-button.html Did a blog post aobut it. Basically almost same thing.

Answer (score 6):

use opacity 0 to just make it invisible. Then use background for making it looks like what you want.

```
<style>
.my_custom_googleplusone{
overflow: hidden;
background: url(blahblah.png);
}

.my_custom_googleplusone:hover{
background: url(blahblah2.png);
}
</style>

<div class="my_custom_googleplusone">
  /// GOOGLE BUTTON WITH OPACITY OF 0 (and z-index 1 with absolute position);
</div>
```

Comment: I still had issues with strange parts of the Google button that are sometimes not visible knocking it out of alignment.

Answer (score 4):

You can overlay an image and keep functionality:

http://tcg.ellininc.com/buttonTest/

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js"></script>
<style>
.my_custom_googleplusone{
    overflow: hidden;
    background-image: url(styled.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 30px;
    width: 161px;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
}
.my_custom_googleplusone:hover{
    visibility: hidden;
}

.hideMe {
    height: 30px;
    width: 161px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1; !Important
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div><g:plusone></g:plusone></div><br />
    <div class="my_custom_googleplusone"></div>
    <div class="hideMe"><g:plusone></g:plusone></div>
</body>
```

My apologies for any extraneous css.

Answer (score 4):

If you were willing to use JavaScript, this will give a more *official experience*.

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" onclick="gPlus('http://example.com');" title="+1">
    <img src="custom-image.png" alt="Google+ +1 Button">
</a>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function gPlus(url){
    window.open(
        'https://plus.google.com/share?url='+url,
        'popupwindow',
        'scrollbars=yes,width=800,height=400'
    ).focus();
    return false;
}
```

If you include that function globally, you can have such buttons all over the place without using multiple, lengthy, in-line `onClick`s.

Answer (score 3):

I used Chrome's element inspector to figure out the elements to target (you could also use Firebug):

The original sprite for +1 is here: https://ssl.gstatic.com/s2/oz/images/stars/po/Publisher/sprite.png

On my implementation, the rendered `<a>` has a classes of `a-sb-ig-e` and `a-sb-ig-ps-e` and its parent is a `<div>` with a class of `a-sb-ML`

From there, you could simply style the button within your own CSS. Similarly, you can also style the counter bubble by inspecting it and figuring out its element's classes.

**Edit:** since the +1 button is called within an iframe, what I described above won't work. What you could do instead is target the +1 div and set its opacity to 0, then place it on top of your own image. The div ID to target is `#___plusone_0`

Comment: What kind of problems are you running into? Have you tried adding `!important` to your style? I've successfully styled the `#___plusone_0` container DIV. I didn't try positioning it, but I presume it should work.

Comment: Are we actually allowed to use a different image or is it against Google's ToS?

Comment: @billygates Good point. Technically, it is against the ToS: "Publishers may not alter or obfuscate the +1 Button, and Publishers may not associate the +1 Button with advertising content, such as putting the +1 Button on or adjacent to an ad, unless authorized to do so by Google." However I think it's intended to prevent fraud and there may be legitimate reasons to modify the Google+ button (code validation for example).

Answer (score 3):

Considering the button resides in an iframe and due to cross-domain restrictions, altering this is unlikely.

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution for using a custom icon for the official google +1 code

[+1 Button - Google+ Platform - Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/+/web/+1button/)

```
<style type="text/css">
.google-plus-container { 
    position: absolute; /* just to position the container where i wante the button, position absoliute or relative is required*/ 
    right: 0; 
    top: 0; }
.google-plus-iframe { 
    z-index: 1; 
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)"; 
    filter: alpha(opacity=0); 
    -moz-opacity: 0; 
    -khtml-opacity: 0; 
    opacity: 0; 
}
.google-plus-icon { 
    z-index: -1; 
    width: 32px; 
    height: 20px; 
    background: transparent url(http://static.educations.com/masterpages/pics/icons/social/gplusbw.png) no-repeat; 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0; 
    right: 0; 
}
```

```
<div class="google-plus-container">
    <div class="google-plus-icon"></div>
    <div class="google-plus-iframe">
        <!-- Place this tag where you want the +1 button to render. -->
        <div class="g-plusone" data-size="medium" data-annotation="none"></div>

        <!-- Place this tag after the last +1 button tag. -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.___gcfg = { lang: 'sv' };

            (function () {
                var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
                po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js';
                var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
            })();
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

Works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

You should use this now: https://plus.google.com/share?url=URL_HERE