# How to get response from google share api without using google button?

Tags: google-plus

```
('#main-block').on('click', '.social .gplus-icon', function(event){           
        var link = $(this).parents('.post').children('.description').children('a').attr('href');
        var url = 'https://plus.google.com/share?url='+link;
        window.open(url, 'Share', 'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=600,width=600');
        return true;
    });
```

I am working on web-app and my issue is:

I want response from google plus share api for notification purpose

Answer (score 2):

I have found a work around for this issue. Please find the below link to jsfiddle for the solution that i have come up with.

The solution is to intercept the onmessage window from google-plus share.

[https://jsfiddle.net/LeoJoy/g3hyx8p7/1//](https://jsfiddle.net/g3hyx8p7/)

```
<div style="width:40px !important" data-action="share" 
class="g-plus" id="share-googleplus"></div>

 gapi.plus.render('share-googleplus', {
      action: "share",
      href: 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6585722/use-custom-image-for-google1-button'         
    })

window.onmessage = function (mes)
{
    var s = mes.data.replace("!_", "");
    s = $.parseJSON(s);
    if (s.s.indexOf("_g_restyleMe") != -1 && Object.keys(s.a[0]).length == 1 && s.a[0].hasOwnProperty("height")) {
       alert("shared to goole")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the only way to initiate a Share on Google+ is to use our Share button widget. There is no other option. However, there are configuration options for the button so that it will fit with your site, which you can find at https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/.

Comment: My another Question is how to get response from G+ after clicking on share button

Comment: A callback for the Share button is a known feature request. If you Star this issue in our Issue Tracker, you will receive an email each time we update the issue.  https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=232

Comment: Is there any way I can share something on google+ without leaving the the app that requested the share?. Currently the button for Share takes me to Safari on iPhone to share, which is less than desirable. Could I just sign a request to Share with my OAuth token?, would this be ok?