# Google+ custom sign-in button for mysite

Tags: php, google-plus

```
  <div id="signin-button" class="show">
 <div class="g-signin" data-callback="loginFinishedCallback"
  data-approvalprompt="force"
  data-clientid="fsdfsfsdf5435.apps.googleusercontent.com"
  data-scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"
  data-height="short"
  data-cookiepolicy="http://www.exmple.com/"

  >
</div>
```

This code displays a Google+ Sign-In button, but I want to use my own Google+ button image.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use custom image for Google+1 button?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6585722/use-custom-image-for-google1-button)

Answer (score 0):

Did you read the [Customizing the sign-in button](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/#customizing_the_sign-in_button) docs? There is an example and code for demonstrating one possible way to use your own HTML markup and CSS or images to design a button.

Also, you must follow the [Google+ branding guidelines](https://developers.google.com/+/branding-guidelines) for your custom button.

Answer (score -3):

I have found this image:
https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-2r7nkB71SpM/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAhIc/VGd2iUHqsNw/s46-c-k-no/photo.jpg
 on google, it is the google+ logo, i dont know how the google plus logo comes up on your screen with that code.

I dont know why, but i'm guessing its this one "fsdfsfsdf5435.apps.googleusercontent.com" but dont hang me if i'm wrong.