# Custom Google plus button callback

Tags: javascript, google-plus

I have this simple HTML layout:

```
<html>
   <head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js"></script>

   <script>
   gapi.plusone.render("mybutton");

   function myCallback(jsonParam) {
       alert("URL: " + jsonParam.href + " state: " + jsonParam.state);
   }
   </script>
   </head>

   <body>
      <a target="_blank" id="mybutton" data-callback="myCallback" href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com">Share on G+</a>
   </body>

</html>
```

I have a custom google plus button with id called `mybutton`. I render it as a plus button using gapi.plus.render function.

I have a callback function that should render when a URL is shared on G plus but for some reason the event is not firing. Is there something wrong in my code or the callback only works with native gplus buttons?

Comment: Did you manage to get this right eventually?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to put the script tag at the end of the page (right after the body tags), so that the page rendering would finish before you call your script.

Correction:

Use the following code inside the script tags to render that button with the callback in the rendering call:

gapi.plusone.render("mybutton", {
                     "callback": myCallback
                    });

Comment: tried that but that's not the problem the code works well if i specify class as `g-plusone` but if i do that, it will get the official look of the g plus button and replace my custom css

Comment: this is a callback on the rendering event. I want a callback when the user actually shares the link not when the button is loaded

Comment: Actually it isn't!  This is setting up the data-callback functionality on that button.

Comment: this worked well because it's using the official button...i want a custom button with my own design and

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6585722/use-custom-image-for-google1-button