# Share with Google plus and get success or not in response

Tags: javascript, php, google-plus

I want to share URL with Google plus, after successful share I need response of success or failure.

I did it and also getting response but if i closed popup without share, then also `onPlusDone` function executed.

**So, I need something that will tell me success of share.**

Below is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function onPlusDone(reponse) {
          console.log(reponse);

            var res = 'success';
             $.ajax({
                    type:"POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {
                        res:res,
                    },
                    url: HOST+'user/success_share',
                    success:function(result){

                    }
                })
      }
     function myCallback(jsonParam) {

         console.log("URL: " + jsonParam.href + " state: " + jsonParam.state);

      }
</script>


<g:plusone size="medium" href="http://myshareurl/" callback="myCallback"  onendinteraction="onPlusDone"></g:plusone>

<script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
    var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
    po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
  })();
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

I have found a work around for this issue. Please find the below link to jsfiddle for the solution that i have come up with.

The solution is to intercept the onmessage window from google-plus share.

https://jsfiddle.net/g3hyx8p7/

```
<div style="width:40px !important" data-action="share" 
class="g-plus" id="share-googleplus"></div>

 gapi.plus.render('share-googleplus', {
      action: "share",
      href: 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6585722/use-custom-image-for-google1-button'         
    })

window.onmessage = function (mes)
{
    var s = mes.data.replace("!_", "");
    s = $.parseJSON(s);
    if (s.s.indexOf("_g_restyleMe") != -1 && Object.keys(s.a[0]).length == 1 && s.a[0].hasOwnProperty("height")) {
       alert("shared to goole")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There currently is not a way to detect that a user has shared content that is supported by the Google+ API.